# Pasar variable Python de una funcion a otra para compararla con la variable de una base de datos sql

Tags: python, sql

estoy intentando pasar la variable de dentro de un campo **Entry** 
   alojada en un **def** a otro para cuando se pulse el boton aceptar me coja mi 
   variable **id** escrita y me la compare con la **id** de mi base de datos el 
   problema es  que cuando intento ejecutarlo me salta con este error:

> obtener() missing 1 required positional argument: 'myid'

Mi tabla estaria generada de esta forma

```
micursor.execute("CREATE TABLE alumnos (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NOMBRE VARCHAR(20), APELLIDOS VARCHAR(20), PASSWORD VARCHAR(20), COMENTARIOS VARCHAR(100))")

def insertar():
  conexionBBDD = sqlite3.connect("Form")
  micursor = conexionBBDD.cursor()
  nombre = entry_2.get()
  apellidos = entry_3.get()
  password = entry_4.get()
  comentario = entry_5.get("1.0",END)
  alumnoslist= [(nombre,apellidos,password,comentario)]

micursor.executemany(
'INSERT INTO alumnos(ID,NOMBRE,APELLIDOS,PASSWORD,COMENTARIOS) 
VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)', alumnoslist)
conexionBBDD.commit()
```

y esta las variable que le quiero pasar

```
def leer():
    id_ventana = Tk()
    id_ventana.geometry('400x80')
    label_6 = Label(id_ventana, text="ID",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
    label_6.place(x=5,y=25)

    entry_6 = Entry(id_ventana)
    entry_6.place(x=120,y=25)
    myid=entry_6.get()
    Button(id_ventana, text='Aceptar',width=8,height=1,bg='gray',fg='white',command=obtener).place(x=280,y=20)





def obtener(myid):

    micursor.execute('SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE ID = ?',(myid,))
```

Comment: Que es lo que esperas que haga cuando pones esto: `myid()`????

Comment: esperaba coger el dato introducido en leer

Comment: y ya te diste cuenta que es una variable y no una función verdad??

Comment: si perdona es que lo estaba editando y no me di cuenta de eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado para pasar la variable la declaras primero fuera de las funciones así:

```
MyID= StringVar()
```

Luego la declaras global dentro de la clase para que no sea estatica y pueda ir cambiando

```
def leer():

global MyID
```

En el campo que quieras comparar la id le metes la variable declarada

```
entry_6 = Entry(id_ventana, textvariable=MyID)
```

Al botón que sirve para comparar le añades lambda y le pasas el campo donde metes la id y el frame de la ventana

```
Button(id_ventana, text='Aceptar',command= lambda: obtener(entry_6.get(),id_ventana))
```

En la funcion que sirve para ejecutar la sentencia sql le pasas

```
def obtener(MyID,id_ventana):
```

y lo comparas

```
strsql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE ID = ?"
micursor.execute(strsql,MyID)
```